# UML Sequence Diagram multiple (OneOf) messages

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I know that with Sequence Diagram, one can present some combined fragment such as alt (if/else), option (while), loop, break and parallel.

But is it possible to represent the following relation:

Actor sends 1 of the message from message set (3 messages).
In the screenshot, the actor wants to send TestOperation or TestOperation2 or TestOperation3, the reply would be the same in the complex system.

Is above possible or do I have to draw 3 sequence diagram with the only change being the message sent?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: yes, you can do that. Since you use asynch messages the calls pile up. But that's only possible if the called object can handle concurrent calls. Or the other way around: it must be implemented in a way that it can receive asynchronous calls.